# Kotlin polymorphism - receive argument cannot have type overriden, but return argument can?

Tags: kotlin, polymorphism

Perhaps I'm tired or not thinking straight, or perhaps this is just something I've never tried before.

I have a base data type, let's call it `Foo`, and an interface, let's call this `Problem` which exposes some functions that work with this `Foo` data type.

One of the interface functions *returns* a `Foo` and one of the functions *recieves* a `Foo`.

Then, I inherit from `Foo`, to create a new data type, let's call it `Bar`, I then implement the `Problem` interface, and in the overrides, I override the type of `Foo` to be `Bar`.

For the function which *returns* the `Foo`, the usage of the `Bar` override works. However, for the function that *receives* the `Foo`, the usage of the `Bar` override does not work:

```
open class Foo(
    open val name: String
)

interface Problem {
    fun setFoo(foo: Foo)
    fun getFoo() : Foo
}

data class Bar(
    override val name: String
) : Foo(
    name = name
)

class ProblemImpl : Problem {
    override fun setFoo(foo: Bar) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }

    override fun getFoo(): Bar {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
}
```

`setFoo overrides nothing`

Now, it might seem obvious; just don't override the types like this! You can just pass `Bar` instances, and due to polymorphism, they will be received as `Foo` instances. But, for complicated reasons I won't go into here, I cannot do this (think declaring Dao interface in library, and overriding it in consuming app with Room annotations...)

I suppose I could have the interface be type parameterized... like:

```
interface Problem<T: Foo> {
   fun setFoo(foo: T)
   fun getFoo() : T
}
```

In fact, I think I've just answered my own question... I'll try with templating now, but I have a hunch it will fail at compile time as Room annotation processor might not be able to deal with template interfaces... in any case, can anyone tell me why the function that *receives* cannot be overriden with a subtype whilst the function that *returns* can?

Comment: As far as I can tell, your problem has nothing to do with inheritance. You just need to implement every method of the interface. And you do not do that with _fun setFoo(foo: Bar)_.

Comment: @lukas.j - But `getFoo() : Bar` is considered a valid implementation of the `Problem` interfaces `getFoo() : Foo` function... you can easily validate this by copying the code from my question to an IDE

Comment: You can define a return a type which is a subtype of the supertype defined in the interface. But with arguments this is not possible. The problem lays in your sentence: "But, for complicated reasons I won't go into here, I cannot do this." There is probably a solution there.

Comment: I see. In my defense, I figured out what you just stated from the compiler already. My question is, why? I.e. why can't I define arguments that are subtypes of the supertypes of the respective arguments defined on the function on the interface? Regardless, I think I am figuring a solution out with generics.

Comment: If your overridden `get` function returns a `Bar`, then that `is` a `Foo`, so it's doing what it's supposed to. But if your overridden `set` function specifically requires a `Bar`, then it won't accept `Foo`s in general, so that *isn't* doing what it's supposed to

Comment: Why? Because in getFoo a return type Bar satisfies the interface, since Bar is a subtype of Foo. In regard of setFoo it should be clear that this does not work, because any caller of setFoo must be able to handover a Foo argument.

Comment: Ah that does make sense lukas

Comment: I think your idea to go with generics makes more sense (without knowing the details).

Comment: Yea, it does, it's almost working, but as expected, room annotation processor is shitting the bed....

Perhaps I need to rethink the entire design. I'm trying to produce a library that intermediates between API and local cache, where local cache is injected into the library such that the library doesn't need to care how it's actually implement (could be room, could be realm, or some other DB).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> in any case, can anyone tell me why the function that receives cannot be overriden with a subtype whilst the function that returns can?

The limitation arises as a consequence of [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle): if Bar is a subtype of Foo, you should be able to use a Bar wherever you use a Foo.

Let's look at the two situations:

1. The function `getFoo()` returns Foo. In a subtype, you return Bar. Since each Bar is a Foo (as Bar is a subtype of Foo), you can use your overridden version of getFoo() in each place you use the base version - it always returns a Foo (which just happens to be Bar, a specific type of Foo). Everything works just fine.
2. The function `setFoo()` receives a Foo. In a subtype, you want it to accept Bar. Now, someone is using your subtype through a reference of the base type. They pass to `setFoo()` a Foo which is not a Bar. But your `setFoo()` in this case only accepts Bar. This means you can't use your subclass in place of the base class, which violates Liskov substitution principle and causes the whole idea of subclassing to collapse. Therefore, the choice is for the language to not allow a subclass to accept Bar in place of Foo.

You can also read on [covariance and contravariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) for more exploration of the topic when subtypes can be used in place of their supertypes.

Comment: Thanks Michal, also, this is *always* the SOLID principle that trips me up